# Get 1 message from each topic subscribed to in Kafka - KafkaConsumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using the Java Kafka Consumer API to create a KafkaConsumer as follows to subscribe to all the topics with that regex pattern:

```
Pattern topicPattern = Pattern.compile("mssql-.*");
KafkaConsumer<String, JsonNode> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(topicPattern);
```

And from the tutorials, this is how I get records:

```
  while (true) {
  ConsumerRecords<String, JsonNode> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
  for (ConsumerRecord<String, JsonNode> record : records)
    System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());

}
```

This prints out all the messages from all the topics. How do I print just 1 message from each topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can set consumer config `max.poll.records` to 1 by default is 500

Comment: This setting is for the whole consumer. It doesn't guarantee 1 record per topic, just the next available poll loop (could get 2 records from the same topic in a row)